# Realloc Crashing on Passed Pointer

Tags: c, realloc

I can't seem to find a question that matches exactly what I'm doing, so here goes. Below is a cut down version of my C app down to where a problem lies. I know it's ugly code and missing a few error checks but it was just for me to figure out this problem. As it stand the sample below should convert all 'A's to 'BCDE's. The comments in the code describe the issue. (runMe is executed first)

```
int runMe2(char *in, char **buffer) {
    long x;
    long b_size = 0; 
    long i_size = 1000;
    long i = 0;
    char t_buffer[1006];

    // Initial malloc small as it will grow
    *buffer = (char *)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*buffer, "");
    for (x = 0; x < 999; x++)
        t_buffer[x] = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < strlen(in); x++) {
        if (i >= i_size) {
            char *r_buffer;
            b_size = b_size + 1006*sizeof(char);
            i_size = 0;
            // Here is where the problem is.
            // The first time through, i=1000, b_size=1006 and everything is fine
            // The second time throgh, i=1004, b_size=2012 and the heap crashes on the realloc
            r_buffer = (char *)realloc(*buffer, b_size);
            if (r_buffer == NULL)
                exit(0);
            *buffer = r_buffer;
            strcat(*buffer, t_buffer);
            for (x = 0; x < 999; x++)
                t_buffer[x] = 0;
        }
        if (in[x] == 'A') {
            t_buffer[i++] = 'B';
            t_buffer[i++] = 'C';
            t_buffer[i++] = 'D';
            t_buffer[i++] = 'E';
        }
    }
}

int runMe() {
    char *out;
    char in[30000];
    int x = 0;

    // Set up a 29,999 character string
    for (x = 0; x < 30000; x++)
        in[x] = 'A';
    in[29999] = 0;
    // Send it as pointer so we can do other things here
    runMe2(in, &out);
    // Eventually, other things will happen here
    free(out);
}
```

Comment: do you mean to damage `x` when you reset `t_buffer` after realloc, and why not just `memset`? doesn't `x` run off the end of `t_buffer`?

Comment: what a ugly piece of code; you are doing a lot of unnecesary operations and you are using cople of not really neded "helper" values

Comment: I don't know what you *think* this does, but from what I can see it concats BCDE into t_buffer for every A encountered in the put string, eventually dumping the buffer into a growth-target *All other chars != 'A' are LOST.* If that is intentional there are *much* easier ways to do this, but something tells me that even with your crash 'fixed' this code will not do near what you think it will.

Comment: If this is a string replace function, a simpler way would be to first count all the A's then calculate your memory requirements on that: bytes = strlen(in) - number_of_As + (number_of_As * 4) + 1, where the 4 is for "BCDE". Then loop thru, replacing as you go into the new mem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (i >= i_size) {
  ...
  i_size = 0;
  ...
}
if (in[x] == 'A') {
  t_buffer[i++] = 'B';
  ...
```

This can't be right. You'll be writing past the end of `t_buffer` if `in` is ever longer than the original `i_size`. You probably meant to reset `i` there, not `i_size`.

Then you're using string functions with `t_buffer` when you've not guaranteed that it is properly null-terminated - you initialize the first thousand values, but overwrite those in your loop. If you're going to use `strcat` and friends, you need to take more care to make sure it stays null-terminated. But using [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html) would lead to simpler code since you know the lengths of the arrays involved.

```
for (x = 0; x < strlen(in); x++) {
  ...
  for (x = 0; x < 999; x++)
    ...
    t_buffer[x] = 0;
```

This can't be right either, as spotted by [Useless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212858/useless). Use a second variable for that, or better use [`memset`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun here's a different algo that works and is much simpler than yours:

```
int runMe2(char *in, char **buffer)
{
    // Count number of A's
    int number_of_As = 0;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; 0 != in[i]; i++) {
        if (in[i] == 'A') {
            number_of_As += 1;
        }
    }

    // If number_of_As == 0, you can just do a strdup here and return

    // Because of 1st loop, i == strlen(in), no need to call strlen
    long bytes = (i - number_of_As + (number_of_As * 4) + 1) * sizeof(char);
    // Error check here

    // Only 1 memeory allocation needed
    *buffer = (char *)malloc(bytes);

    // Simple copy loop
    for (i = 0, j = 0; 0 != in[i]; i++) {
            // If it's an A replace
        if (in[i] == 'A') {
            (*buffer)[j++] = 'B';
            (*buffer)[j++] = 'C';
            (*buffer)[j++] = 'D';
            (*buffer)[j++] = 'E';
        }
            // Not an A, just copy
        else {
            (*buffer)[j++] = in[i];
        }
    }
    // Null terminate
    (*buffer)[j] = 0;

    return j;
}
```

Comment: +1: I totally like this answer. However, factor the byte-calculation. `-number_of_As + (number_of_As * 4) ` is just (number_of_As*3). =P